# Couldn't save my product listing after editing, error: "product does not exist", found out its due to related products OOS. But why?

Tags: magento2, product, error

Couldn't **save** my **product listing** after **editing**, shown an **error message**

> "product does not exist"

found out the cause is due to related products being OOS. But why is it affecting the main product listing?

Would like to find out if this is a Magento logic or a bug that needs to be fixed.

Thanks in advance and any help welcomed!

Comment: What version of Magento?

Comment: Hi, its Version 2.0

Comment: So you save product a and it gives you an error because product b that's related to product a is OOS?

Comment: Yes, that's what i meant. Product B is tagged as a related product under product A.

Comment: Do you have any extensions? When you set product b back to in stock then it saves product a without any issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had a check with Magento 2.2.5 default setup and it is being saved without any issue when related product of a product is out of stock. Please check with customization you did or any other third party extension(s) installed at your store.